# How do you get summarized statistics on a whole set of queries in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance

I'm trying to tune a few mechanics for operations I make on a database in SQL Server 2008.

In order to pick the best approach of the problem I often use `SET STATISTICS IO ON`, but it's not really handy when I compare a long set of statements with another.

So for example, how could I know the whole reads/writes it takes to a T-SQL statement like the following:

```
WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN
 <some statements>
 SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

Thank for your help (forgive me for my poor English).

Comment: SQL Profiler can show aggregated data (including reads/writes) for entire batches as well as for individual statements. This is not a T-SQL method, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table variable and in it track the duration of sections of code as they get executed.

For example:

```
DECLARE @Tracking TAABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TheStep varchar(50),
    Start datetime,
    End datetime
)

DECLARE
    @TheStep varchar(50),
    @Start datetime,
    @End datetime

-- first block of code to track

SET @TheStep = 'Grab data from MyTable.'
SET @Start = getdate()

SELECT * FROM MyTable

SET @End = getdate()

INSERT INTO @Tracking (TheStep, Start, End)
SELECT @TheStep, @Start, @End

-- reset variables for next batch of commands to measure
SELECT @TheStep = NULL, @Start = NULL, @End = NULL

-- after all is said and done, display the results along with duration (ms) for each.
SELECT TheStep, DATEDIFF(ms, Start, End)
FROM @Tracking
```

Comment: Time spent is not a good enough measurement, it doesn't help making an opinions on locks/concurrency (while IO stats do).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the dynamic management view [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead of `SET STATISTICS IO`?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Read_and_Write') 
  DROP TABLE Read_and_Write

CREATE TABLE Read_and_Write (
  RowID INT NOT NULL,
  RowValue CHAR(2000)
) 

CHECKPOINT
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE 
GO

INSERT Read_and_Write (RowID, RowValue) 
SELECT TOP 10000
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
  'X'
FROM sys.all_objects s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects s2 

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Read_and_Write
WHERE RowID <= 500

SELECT 
  cast( (select [processing-instruction(q)] = 
  case when [sql_handle] is null then ''
       else (substring(s.text,(q.statement_start_offset + 2) / 2,
     (case when q.statement_end_offset = -1 
           then len(convert(nvarchar(max),s.text)) * 2
           else q.statement_end_offset
      end - q.statement_start_offset) / 2))
  end for xml path('') ) as xml) AS sql_text,
  last_worker_time,
  last_elapsed_time,
  last_logical_reads,
  last_physical_reads,
  last_logical_writes,
  last_rows,
  p.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats q
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text([sql_handle]) s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ([plan_handle]) p
```

Comment: I'm not interested in having stats on a single execution (last one in your code) of different statements. But on stats on the "current" X (X = 1000 in the loop) executions of a set of statements.

Comment: Are you looking to gather the total read / writes for a batch of statements? Or do you want the line item read / writes for each statement, but be able to specific which batch you want to look at?

Comment: Your first proposal is what I'm looking for. But I guess the logic involved would be easy to adapt to achieve your second proposal.